# Issue in Logging into files using Logger library in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, logging

I have to create a Java Service that logs certain data into files using the Logger library. The log data for each day is contained in a single file which is generated by appending the date to a base file name. The following is the Servlet code for the above

```
........
import java.util.logging.Logger;
.........
public class track extends HttpServlet {
private String BaseDirectory;
private String BaseFileName;
private String FullFileName;
private Logger logger;
private FileHandler fh;
private ServletContext sc;
@Override
public void init(){        
    ServletConfig config=getServletConfig();                
    BaseDirectory=config.getInitParameter("LogBaseDir");
    BaseFileName=config.getInitParameter("BaseLogFile");        
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    sc=getServletContext();             
    FullFileName=getFullFileName();        
    String realPath = sc.getRealPath("/"+BaseDirectory);
    String FullFilePath=realPath+"/"+FullFileName;        
    createFile(realPath,FullFilePath);
    String qs=request.getQueryString();
    if(qs!=null && qs.contains("paramjson")){
        logData(request.getQueryString(),FullFilePath);            
    }
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {                        
}

private String getFullFileName() {
    Date date=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");        
    String FullName=this.BaseFileName+"_"+df.format(date)+".log";              
    return FullName;
}

private void createFile(String realPath, String FullFilePath) throws IOException {  
    /* Creates the base logging Directory denoted by realPath.
       Checkes whether the log file denoted by FullFilePath exists or not. If it doesn't,
       it is created.
    */      
    boolean status1,status2;        
    File file=new File(realPath);
    synchronized(this){          
      status1=file.mkdirs();
    }
    if (status1){
        sc.log("Directory Created");
    }
    else{
        sc.log("Directory already exists");            
    }
    file=new File(FullFilePath);
    synchronized(this){
        file=new File(FullFilePath);
        status2=file.exists();
        if(status2){
            sc.log("File already exists with name "+FullFileName);            
        }
        else{
            if(file.createNewFile()){
                sc.log("File Creation Successfull with name "+FullFileName);                
            }
            else{
                sc.log("File Creation Failed with name "+FullFileName);
            }
        }
    }                
}

private void logData(String queryString, String FullFilePath) throws IOException {
        logger=Logger.getLogger("ClickLogger");
        if(fh==null){
            fh=new FileHandler(FullFilePath);                                      
            logger.addHandler(fh);
        }                                   
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();              
        fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
        String qs  = decodeData(queryString);            
        logger.log(Level.INFO,qs);             
}

private String decodeData(String queryString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {        
    return (java.net.URLDecoder.decode(queryString,"UTF-8"));
}
}
```

The functions are self explanatory. The general sequence of execution takes place normally and as required. However, in case of the following two circumstances:

a) The code is modified

b) The log file generated is intentionally deleted (manually)

The original log file gets appended by a number (eg. Data.log.1  Data.log.2 etc). The data is logged correctly but into multiple files  as mentioned above. So to get things back on track, I have to delete the base log directory, restart tomcat and then proceed.

The second situation of log file being deleted is not that alarming as in a production environment that would rarely be happening. However when I modify my code and deploy the war file, I do not want to restart my server every time.

While working on this issue, I modified the following line in `logData` as follows :

```
if(fh==null){
     fh=new FileHandler(FullFilePath);                                      
     logger.addHandler(fh);
 }
```

to

```
if(fh==null){
     fh=new FileHandler(FullFilePath,true);                                      
     logger.addHandler(fh);
}
```

This solves the problem of a new file (the ones appended by numbers) being created. However, no more data is now logged into the file and it remains empty. What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: R u using [java.util.logging.Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) or [org.apache.log4j.Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) ?

Comment: I am using java.util.logging.Logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The original log file gets appended by a number (eg. Data.log.1 Data.log.2 etc). The data is logged correctly but into multiple files as mentioned above

You have to add code to [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#removeHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)) and [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#close()) your created FileHandler when your application is undeployed.  Every time you redeploy your app you are opening another FileHandler targeting the same location.  Every open FileHandler has to write to a unique file path so the FileHandler will add that digit to make the name unique.

You should also fix the thread-safety issues in your code with lazy creating the logger and synchronizing on the servlet.  The lack of thread-safety in creating that logger could result in opening multiple FileHandlers given the correct conditions.